# Floating wrapfigure leaves whole article text wrapped if unnumbered sections are used

Tags: sectioning, wrapfigure, unnumbered-sections

I have the following article:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Pig chislic turducken short ribs boudin jerky venison sausage ground round cupim strip steak beef ribs swine buffalo sirloin. Jowl tongue porchetta beef ribs boudin biltong filet mignon pork belly ham hock meatball. Bacon landjaeger strip steak, venison andouille shankle ground round tail doner corned beef pork loin rump tri-tip porchetta jowl. Short loin chicken pork belly sirloin pancetta jerky doner capicola cupim rump spare ribs andouille shankle salami. Chuck shoulder short loin, rump salami burgdoggen short ribs swine beef drumstick shank andouille frankfurter. Pork landjaeger ground round chicken, biltong picanha shank meatloaf strip steak cupim sausage capicola. Cupim short loin prosciutto pork loin cow bresaola pastrami salami short ribs strip steak frankfurter rump biltong picanha ground round.

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{.5\textwidth} 
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{frog}
    \end{center}
    \caption{this is my caption}
\end{wrapfigure}



\section*{Meat}
Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork loin bresaola t-bone ball tip boudin pig brisket alcatra turducken ground round pork chop chuck shank. Turkey turducken salami cupim jowl buffalo short loin beef ribs pork belly shoulder picanha ground round burgdoggen. Filet mignon tongue alcatra, bacon picanha ribeye hamburger pastrami salami landjaeger brisket shoulder ground round drumstick. Pork tail biltong boudin, shoulder beef ribs brisket. Meatball doner pork belly, bacon salami chislic pork chop rump sausage kevin buffalo hamburger tail turducken. Pork loin beef tri-tip, shank doner spare ribs fatback swine pancetta.

Spare ribs turkey strip steak salami sirloin bresaola rump jerky. Beef ribs frankfurter pork loin pig sirloin. Cupim kielbasa jowl, porchetta turducken brisket pastrami fatback spare ribs short ribs jerky t-bone chislic. Tail turducken pastrami, capicola tongue kevin kielbasa ham hock corned beef cupim sausage shoulder. Tri-tip doner swine biltong salami. Frankfurter buffalo corned beef bresaola, pastrami brisket fatback ground round ham meatloaf pork loin hamburger jerky.

Pig chislic turducken short ribs boudin jerky venison sausage ground round cupim strip steak beef ribs swine buffalo sirloin. Jowl tongue porchetta beef ribs boudin biltong filet mignon pork belly ham hock meatball. Bacon landjaeger strip steak, venison andouille shankle ground round tail doner corned beef pork loin rump tri-tip porchetta jowl. Short loin chicken pork belly sirloin pancetta jerky doner capicola cupim rump spare ribs andouille shankle salami. Chuck shoulder short loin, rump salami burgdoggen short ribs swine beef drumstick shank andouille frankfurter. Pork landjaeger ground round chicken, biltong picanha shank meatloaf strip steak cupim sausage capicola. Cupim short loin prosciutto pork loin cow bresaola pastrami salami short ribs strip steak frankfurter rump biltong picanha ground round.

\end{document}
```

After the wrapped figure, the remaining article text gets wrapped too, although there is no image:

[image]

But if I exchange `\section*{Frog}` with `\section{Frog}`, it works as expected:

[image]

Am I missing something here? Why does `wrapfigure` not work with unnumbered sections?

Comment: The issue already popped out in the past; `wrapfig` does not like appearing before starred sectioning commands. A quick fix is to but it *after* `\section*`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396932/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58525/82917

Comment: Ok, well what to expect from an unmaintained library from 2003. Too bad there isn't a good alternative. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

This shows how to do it using paracol, `\splitpar` and `\continuepar`.

To manually split paragraphs, first extend paracol to the end of a paragraph, longer than needed in order to locate the end of the figure.  Then add `\splitpar{...}` to include the rest of the last paragraph, and `\continuepar` after `\end{paracol}`.

If the margins appear uneven, add `\sloppy` inside paracol.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\splitpar}[2][\textwidth]{% #1 = width of column (optional), #2 = rest of paragraph after split
  \unskip\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}%
  \global\setbox\textbox=\vbox{\hsize=#1\relax\noindent\strut #2\strut}}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}

\begin{document}
Pig chislic turducken short ribs boudin jerky venison sausage ground round cupim strip steak beef ribs swine buffalo sirloin. Jowl tongue porchetta beef ribs boudin biltong filet mignon pork belly ham hock meatball. Bacon landjaeger strip steak, venison andouille shankle ground round tail doner corned beef pork loin rump tri-tip porchetta jowl. Short loin chicken pork belly sirloin pancetta jerky doner capicola cupim rump spare ribs andouille shankle salami. Chuck shoulder short loin, rump salami burgdoggen short ribs swine beef drumstick shank andouille frankfurter. Pork landjaeger ground round chicken, biltong picanha shank meatloaf strip steak cupim sausage capicola. Cupim short loin prosciutto pork loin cow bresaola pastrami salami short ribs strip steak frankfurter rump biltong picanha ground round.

\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{this is my caption}
\end{figure}
\hrule% remove from final version
\switchcolumn
\sloppy% SOP for narow columns
\section*{Meat}
Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork loin bresaola t-bone ball tip boudin pig brisket alcatra turducken ground round pork chop chuck shank. Turkey turducken salami cupim jowl buffalo short loin beef ribs pork belly shoulder picanha ground round burgdoggen. Filet mignon tongue alcatra, bacon picanha ribeye hamburger pastrami salami landjaeger \splitpar{\fussy brisket shoulder ground round drumstick. Pork tail biltong boudin, shoulder beef ribs brisket. Meatball doner pork belly, bacon salami chislic pork chop rump sausage kevin buffalo hamburger tail turducken. Pork loin beef tri-tip, shank doner spare ribs fatback swine pancetta.}
\end{paracol}
\continuepar

Spare ribs turkey strip steak salami sirloin bresaola rump jerky. Beef ribs frankfurter pork loin pig sirloin. Cupim kielbasa jowl, porchetta turducken brisket pastrami fatback spare ribs short ribs jerky t-bone chislic. Tail turducken pastrami, capicola tongue kevin kielbasa ham hock corned beef cupim sausage shoulder. Tri-tip doner swine biltong salami. Frankfurter buffalo corned beef bresaola, pastrami brisket fatback ground round ham meatloaf pork loin hamburger jerky.

Pig chislic turducken short ribs boudin jerky venison sausage ground round cupim strip steak beef ribs swine buffalo sirloin. Jowl tongue porchetta beef ribs boudin biltong filet mignon pork belly ham hock meatball. Bacon landjaeger strip steak, venison andouille shankle ground round tail doner corned beef pork loin rump tri-tip porchetta jowl. Short loin chicken pork belly sirloin pancetta jerky doner capicola cupim rump spare ribs andouille shankle salami. Chuck shoulder short loin, rump salami burgdoggen short ribs swine beef drumstick shank andouille frankfurter. Pork landjaeger ground round chicken, biltong picanha shank meatloaf strip steak cupim sausage capicola. Cupim short loin prosciutto pork loin cow bresaola pastrami salami short ribs strip steak frankfurter rump biltong picanha ground round.

\end{document}
```

---

While this will not float automatically to the next page, you can manually split the paragraph at the end of a page and start the paracol at the very top.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\splitpar}[2][\textwidth]{% #1 = width of column (optional), #2 = rest of paragraph after split
  \unskip\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}%
  \global\setbox\textbox=\vbox{\hsize=#1\relax\noindent\strut #2\strut}}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}

\begin{document}
\rule{1em}{40\baselineskip}

Pig chislic turducken short ribs boudin jerky venison sausage ground round cupim strip steak beef ribs swine buffalo sirloin. Jowl tongue porchetta beef ribs boudin biltong filet mignon pork belly ham hock meatball. Bacon landjaeger strip steak, venison andouille shankle ground round tail doner corned beef pork loin rump tri-tip porchetta jowl. Short loin chicken pork belly sirloin pancetta \splitpar[\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep]{\sloppy jerky doner capicola cupim rump spare ribs andouille shankle salami. Chuck shoulder short loin, rump salami burgdoggen short ribs swine beef drumstick shank andouille frankfurter. Pork landjaeger ground round chicken, biltong picanha shank meatloaf strip steak cupim sausage capicola. Cupim short loin prosciutto pork loin cow bresaola pastrami salami short ribs strip steak frankfurter rump biltong picanha ground round.}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{this is my caption}
\end{figure}
%\hrule% remove from final version
\switchcolumn
\continuepar
\end{paracol}

\section*{Meat}
Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork loin bresaola t-bone ball tip boudin pig brisket alcatra turducken ground round pork chop chuck shank. Turkey turducken salami cupim jowl buffalo short loin beef ribs pork belly shoulder picanha ground round burgdoggen. Filet mignon tongue alcatra, bacon picanha ribeye hamburger pastrami salami landjaeger brisket shoulder ground round drumstick. Pork tail biltong boudin, shoulder beef ribs brisket. Meatball doner pork belly, bacon salami chislic pork chop rump sausage kevin buffalo hamburger tail turducken. Pork loin beef tri-tip, shank doner spare ribs fatback swine pancetta.

Spare ribs turkey strip steak salami sirloin bresaola rump jerky. Beef ribs frankfurter pork loin pig sirloin. Cupim kielbasa jowl, porchetta turducken brisket pastrami fatback spare ribs short ribs jerky t-bone chislic. Tail turducken pastrami, capicola tongue kevin kielbasa ham hock corned beef cupim sausage shoulder. Tri-tip doner swine biltong salami. Frankfurter buffalo corned beef bresaola, pastrami brisket fatback ground round ham meatloaf pork loin hamburger jerky.

Pig chislic turducken short ribs boudin jerky venison sausage ground round cupim strip steak beef ribs swine buffalo sirloin. Jowl tongue porchetta beef ribs boudin biltong filet mignon pork belly ham hock meatball. Bacon landjaeger strip steak, venison andouille shankle ground round tail doner corned beef pork loin rump tri-tip porchetta jowl. Short loin chicken pork belly sirloin pancetta jerky doner capicola cupim rump spare ribs andouille shankle salami. Chuck shoulder short loin, rump salami burgdoggen short ribs swine beef drumstick shank andouille frankfurter. Pork landjaeger ground round chicken, biltong picanha shank meatloaf strip steak cupim sausage capicola. Cupim short loin prosciutto pork loin cow bresaola pastrami salami short ribs strip steak frankfurter rump biltong picanha ground round.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution works but is rather hard to maintain, since one needs to cut manually at the exact good word. But still better than nothing I guess. It would be great if the command could find automatically the word to cut at ^^

Comment: I just run it without splitting and look.  Adding \hrule to the bottom of the other column helps.

Comment: Yeah make sense. Just have to restart everytime the text change, but it's better than nothing.