# Warnings from using wrapfigures

Tags: floats, environments, paragraphs, warnings, wrapfigure

I losing my mind for some time with the following warnings of which I can't get rid off.

```
line 25 Collision between wrapping environments
line 29 Stationary wrapfigure forced to float
line 31 Stationary wrapfigure forced to float
```

I tried a lot, especially inserting \par or a blank line respectively but still get these kind of
warnings and all solutions from the internet didn't work out. Following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Columnwise mean and standard deviation}
is not an advanced metric and does not reveal any hidden relations, but functions as a quick sanity check. The means and standard deviations of each column are plotted on a log scale. If the plotted values follow the diagonal, the data has comparable means and standard deviations. Moreover, the general results do appear to have a correlation with how well these values follow the diagonal, meaning that if many points deviate from the diagonal, it is likely the cumulative distributions and quantitative measures will follow a similar pattern of deviations.
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example_mean.png}
  \caption{An example of the visualization of the columnwise mean and standard deviation}
  \label{fig:examplemean}
\end{figure}
\textbf{Cumulative Sum} visually inspects the similarity between the distributions per column, the cumulative sum of each column for both the real and the fake data on top of each other are plotted.
This gives one a quite thorough understanding of a column with just one plot, and works for both categorical and continuous columns. Note that this plot does not give any insights into the relations between columns, giving it limited representational power for the whole table. 
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example_cumsum.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the cumulative sum}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Distribution} 
simply shows the distribution of the values of each column plotted with the value on the x-axis and the probability on the y-axis. The bar chart in the background of the figure shows how often values from a certain range (bin) appeared in this specific column of each, the real and fake dataset.
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example_dist.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the distribution}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{Correlations}, the fourth visualization, shows a association table for the real and synthetic data. It gives a clear understanding of what columns have associations with each other, and shows where the synthetic data diverges, indicating struggles that the model had with modeling this relationship. Associated columns are coloured in red, disassociated  columns in blue.
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example_asso.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the correlations via an association table}
\label{fig:exampleasso}
\end{figure}
\textbf{Principle Components Analysis (PCA)} figures show the first two components of a PCA as a scatter plot. PCA is method to reduce high dimensionality of data by using dependencies between dimensions and forming fewer principle components (PCs). With theses PCs, the data can be presented in a lower-dimensional form without losing too much information. Dependencies between dimension can already be seen in the association table above. With PCA again can be checked if the fake data includes the same association between columns as the real data. If the two scatter plots of the first two PCs are similar, one can assume that the associations are also similar, as the dimensionality reduction of PCA into this first two PCs is based on these correlations between the columns.
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example_pca.png}
  \caption{An example of the visualization of the first two components of the PCA}
  \label{fig:examplepca}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here are the used pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it is just warning you that your text paragraphs are too short to fully wrap around the supplied figures. (if you used `example-image` as the image  and chaeck that the problem still shows, we could run your test file and see the result and possibly suggest ways of avoiding the warnings)

Comment: why \textbf{Columnwise mean and standard deviation}  rather than use section commands?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's because this is already embedded in a subsubsection in the original.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle! I'll try to make the figures smaller and see if the warning still occurs.

Comment: `\paragraph` is the next heading level after subsubsection , your bold `\textbf{Principle Components Analysis (PCA)}  `  for example isn't even at the start of a paragraph so comes mid-line and doesn't look like a heading at all?

Comment: No it doesn't. I worked with  `\paragraph{Distribution} $~$ \\`   also, but had the same issues and therefore changed it as I thought that could make the problems.

Comment: don't use `$~$` ???

Comment: Wrapfig is use to wrap text AROUND the figure.  When the text is too short or uses any of a number of things which conflict with wrapfig, it is better to use paracol.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611977/floating-wrapfigure-leaves-whole-article-text-wrapped-if-unnumbered-sections-are/612011?r=SearchResults&s=1|37.1822#612011 for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I first wanted to have a new line after the paragraph caption, that's why I used `$~$ \\ ` .

Comment: @JohnKormylo, paracol is a good hint, I'll surely also will try that out next time!

Comment: just declare the `\paragraph` heading to be display rather than run-in  heading no need for `$~$` weirdness (if you do want to force something `\mbox{}\\ ` not using math mode and not forcing a space in the output would be slightly less weird but still bad markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `example-image` as the images then you get the warnings

```
Package wrapfig Warning: Collision between wrapping environments on input line 
Package wrapfig Warning: Stationary wrapfigure forced to float on input line 29
```

Looking at the output

[image]

You can see that the problem is that the `\textbf` "sections" are not generating enough space  to hold the wrapped figures, and one of them is coming too low on the page to fit.

Changing the `\textbf` to `\paragraph` you still get warnings but a more acceptable result apart from some stretched text

[image]

Then if you give `wrapfig` some help with the number of lines to cut-in at the page break, and ensure the full width figures are inserted between paragraphs not mid paragraphs, it works out OK:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Columnwise mean and standard deviation}
is not an advanced metric and does not reveal any hidden relations, but functions as a quick sanity check. The means and standard deviations of each column are plotted on a log scale. If the plotted values follow the diagonal, the data has comparable means and standard deviations. Moreover, the general results do appear to have a correlation with how well these values follow the diagonal, meaning that if many points deviate from the diagonal, it is likely the cumulative distributions and quantitative measures will follow a similar pattern of deviations.

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
  \caption{An example of the visualization of the columnwise mean and standard deviation}
  \label{fig:examplemean}
\end{figure}


\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}{0.35\textwidth}
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the cumulative sum}
\end{wrapfigure}
\paragraph{Cumulative Sum} visually inspects the similarity between the distributions per column, the cumulative sum of each column for both the real and the fake data on top of each other are plotted.
This gives one a quite thorough understanding of a column with just one plot, and works for both categorical and continuous columns. Note that this plot does not give any insights into the relations between columns, giving it limited representational power for the whole table. 

\paragraph{Distribution} 
simply shows the distribution of the values of each column plotted with the value on the x-axis and the probability on the y-axis. The bar chart in the background of the figure shows how often values from a certain range (bin) appeared in this specific column of each, the real and fake dataset.

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{0.35\textwidth}
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the distribution}
\end{wrapfigure}
\paragraph{Correlations}, the fourth visualization, shows a association table for the real and synthetic data. It gives a clear understanding of what columns have associations with each other, and shows where the synthetic data diverges, indicating struggles that the model had with modeling this relationship. Associated columns are coloured in red, disassociated  columns in blue.

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the correlations via an association table}
\label{fig:exampleasso}
\end{figure}
\paragraph{Principle Components Analysis (PCA)} figures show the first two components of a PCA as a scatter plot. PCA is method to reduce high dimensionality of data by using dependencies between dimensions and forming fewer principle components (PCs). With theses PCs, the data can be presented in a lower-dimensional form without losing too much information. Dependencies between dimension can already be seen in the association table above. With PCA again can be checked if the fake data includes the same association between columns as the real data. If the two scatter plots of the first two PCs are similar, one can assume that the associations are also similar, as the dimensionality reduction of PCA into this first two PCs is based on these correlations between the columns.

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
  \caption{An example of the visualization of the first two components of the PCA}
  \label{fig:examplepca}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

although I notice now that hides the caption of the second wrapfig so perhaps move that earlier before `\paragraph{Distribution}`

[image]

with example-image you can't get two figures on the page at full width as they are too tall so this ends up as 4 pages.

Comment: Great work, thank you! The distribution paragraph is two times included in your example, therefore I had to play around a bit with the number of lines to cut-in and the `\vpsace` to make all captions visible, but the solution you provided works perfectly!

Comment: @Zepp oh sorry I must have accidentally picked it up while moving the wrapfig, but the details are anyway highly dependent on the real text and real images, so ....