# Floating figure in non-breaking box

Tags: minipage, wrapfig

I am looking for a way to have text associated with a figure that will be right justified on the page. The figure should be anchored to the top of the text, basically. I also don't want the text to break over a page; if the block with the figure and the text doesnt fit it should just go to the next page.

I found `minipage` and `wrapfig` through my searches, but `minipage` doesn't fit its box to a `wrapfig` (have also tried `floatflt`), only the text inside; so the figures/text of the next one end up overlapping.

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{floatingfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)circle (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{floatingfigure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in justo et turpis malesuada porttitor rhoncus at felis. Integer varius tincidunt porta. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 

\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{floatingfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{floatingfigure}

Ut nec sollicitudin orci, quis volutpat erat. Integer venenatis tincidunt viverra. Praesent nec mauris convallis, fringilla velit iaculis, imperdiet justo. Proin vestibulum turpis purus. Quisque sed semper metus. 

\end{minipage}
```

This is the result of that code:

[image]

Here is an image I very quickly mocked up. nothing is aligned but it should give a general idea of what I'm after.

[image: mockup]

Comment: `\marginpar`  would do more or less what you ask, as far as I can tell

Comment: can you put a TiKZ figure in a marginpar? i'm getting an error, not sure if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: yes of course you can put a tikzpicture anywhere you can put a letter.

Comment: as you have provided no usable example it s hard to say exactly what you should do. You can not have a marginpar in a minipage, if you want the minipage then you just need to make the minipage with teh text .7\textwidth wide and put the tikzpicture next to it.

Comment: I see, the two minipages solution works much better. Pretty much what I'm after. One question though, what combination of position parameters for the minipages should I use for them to both be anchored to the tops of the minipages? Like I want the text to start at the same place the figure does

Comment: Once can use paracol as a more robust alternative to wrapfig.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611977/floating-wrapfigure-leaves-whole-article-text-wrapped-if-unnumbered-sections-are/612011?r=SearchResults&s=1|37.6946#612011  OTOH, paracol will break across pages.

Comment: use minipage `[t]` and put `\vspace{0pt}` at the start of both so they line up on the top edge

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what i wanted.